# Line height in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4

How do I increase the distance between the lines in Xcode?
I mean in the actual code.

Even when I change the font and font sizes in the Xcode preferences, the code lines are still too close together and it is very annoying.

Comment: OT, but: I use emacs for any editing, and Xcode only for compilation. I find it's best to find one editor you can use for virtually any text editing task, and learn it well, rather than use a different IDE for every language you use.  See also http://dague.net/2011/02/12/productivity-tip-learn-your-tools/

Comment: Yeah, yeah, and emacs is not only a floor wax, but also a dessert topping!

Comment: I also like Emacs, but without the support for autocompletion, it takes very much time with the long method names in Foundation and AppKit, sadly enough. That's the only reason I use Xcode. However, I guess Xcode 4 will change that. :)

Answer (score 19):

Also check out the [Meslo font](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font); an open source customized version of Menlo that comes with much nicer line-spacing.

Comment: I prefered this font above the fonts in other answers. What I like about this font is that it has 3 different versions with different line spacing, so it gives you some freedom to set it to your prefered line spacing. Since GitHub no longer shows the Download button, simply scroll down in the Readme file of the repository to get a direct download link.

Answer (score 7):

Since Xcode 9 you can open your theme file and specify the desired line spacing through the property `DVTLineSpacing`. Example for 1.5 line spacing:

```
<key>DVTLineSpacing</key>
<real>1.5</real>
```

Comment: This is the only actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Prior to Xcode 9, there was no way to change line height. However, now in Xcode 9 the option is available under Xcode>Preferences...>Fonts & Colors at the bottom there is a popup that has the options of "Tight Spacing", "Normal Spacing", and "Relaxed Spacing".

Answer (score 3):

Try using the free, open source [Droid Mono](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Droid+Sans+Mono) font.
It has more line spacing build into the font itself.

The tight line spacing in XCode 4 was driving me crazy too!

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `DVTLineSpacing` property in the `.xccolortheme` file to change the line height.

1. Open any `.xcolortheme` file from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes`
2. Edit the `DVTLineSpacing` key. If there isn't one, add this to the file, replacing `1.8` with the line spacing you want:

```
<key>DVTLineSpacing</key>
<real>1.4</real>
```

3. Close and re-open Xcode

By default Xcode uses `1` for tight spacing, no key for regular spacing, and `1.2` for relaxed spacing.

Tested with Xcode 12.2 and Mac OS 10.15.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom font with whitespace on the top and bottom of the glyphs, install it and set is as the editing font in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:
http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts

and download your favorite font and decompress it. After that, open Mac's TextEdit and Format-->Font-->Show Fonts-->click the setting in the left corner beside "+-" -->Manage Fonts-->Click "+" to add the font you just downloaded.

Now you've successfully added a font in your Mac, and you can choose this font in your Xcode preference. The line height of the new font is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The settings related to font, size, and line spacing in the Xcode editor are part of Xcode's font. Just change the font.

In the main XCode settings -- > Themes, there are options for the Source Editor/Console, the "Theme" on the left is the way to change the font. As you select different Themes the line spacing will change as the line height (spacing) is built into the font itself.
This isn't exactly intuitive--most of us are used to font and line spacing as individual/independent settings.
There is also a drop down in the lower-middle of the window "Tight Spacing, Normal Spacing and Relaxed Spacing" none of which seem to do anything to the linespace vertically relative to each line in your editor, but the spacing between characters on a line (ish).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).